# How object cout prints multiple arguments?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Unlike `printf()` function it do not have format specifier from where compiler guesses the no. of arguments. Then what happens in case of cout?

Comment: It is called chaining. i.e. `cout << a << b` is (`cout <<a) << b`. Where the overload operator returns the stream to pass on.

Comment: How is that related to C actually?

Comment: @Olaf  because i also wanted to know abt little bit of printf in same scenario, so that is how it is related to c actually.

Comment: For printf, you should ask another question then. Or - better - first read about variable argument lists. To be found in the standard and any book about C. In any case, the question as stated now does not cover this, as you can see from the answers given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IOStreams only take *one* argument at a time, so it works just fine. :)

The magic of operator overloading means that this:

```
std::cout << a << b << c;
```

is actually this:

```
std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, a), b), c);
```

or this:

```
std::cout.operator<<(a).operator<<(b).operator<<(c);
```

<sup>(Depending on the types of `a`, `b` and `c`, either [a free function](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46716c4321118dfd) or [a member function](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf434ceb2ed50d83) will be invoked.)</sup>

and each individual call is to an overload that accepts the type you give it. No argument-counting or format strings required, as they are with your *single* calls to `printf`.

Comment: I have a feeling that the letters `a`, `b` and `c` are in the wrong order

Answer (score 2):

`<<` and `>>` operator are overloaded for different data types. No need of format specifier in this case. For `<<` operator following definitions are in `ostream` class:

```
ostream& operator<< (bool val);
ostream& operator<< (short val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned short val);
ostream& operator<< (int val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);
ostream& operator<< (long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long val);
ostream& operator<< (float val);
ostream& operator<< (double val);
ostream& operator<< (long double val);
ostream& operator<< (void* val);
ostream& operator<< (streambuf* sb );
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
ostream& operator<< (ios& (*pf)(ios&));
ostream& operator<< (ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&));
```

Comment: Can u explain it little bit

Comment: These operators returns itself to make call chains. No need to know count of args.

Answer (score 2):

C++ streams have no implementation for inputting/outputting multiple values. They have the formatted input/output operators >>/<<, which separate each output value. Besides these, they have unformatted functions operating on a single value (array)

Example: A single `ostream& operator << (T a);` puts a value 'a' into the stream and returns a reference to the stream, itself. That reference to the stream is eligible to accept a next value 'b' as in `stream << a << b;`

Note: This compiles for defined operators `IStream& operator >> (IStream&, Type)` and `OStream& operator << (OStream&, Type)`, only. A defined operator may be an operator provided by the standard library or a user defined operator.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does not need to guess the number of arguments from `printf`'s format specifier (though some do for better warnings). In case of `cout`, each `<<` is a command to either output something or manipulate the stream, so there is no need for a format specifier.

Comment: then how compiler get to know its no. of arguments? in printf() case

Comment: `printf` is a variadic function. A compiler may (cannot in general) not verify the compliance of number of effective arguments passed with the format string. Modern ones (like gcc or lint tool) do such with a simple string analysis, but they can only do it in the case of string format literals.

Comment: @sony: Guesswork and trust. There's a reason we don't use `printf` any more. :)